# Не работает плавный переход

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В `.maindiv` добавил `transition-duration: 0.5s`, но переход по прежнему остается исходным. В `linear-gradient` не работает плавный переход. Пожалуйста помогите!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maindiv {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(53, 13, 80, 0.74), rgba(128, 19, 19, 0.514)), url("https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 37.5rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  position: relative;
}

.maindiv::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.maindiv:hover::before {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}

.pclass {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.pclass2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 120px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  width: 400px;
}

.maindiv:hover .pclass2 {
  right: 160px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="maindiv">
    <p class="pclass">FREE SARAH</p>
    <hr class="line">
    <p class="pclass2">SARAH LIKES TO WATCH CLOUDS. SHE'S QUITE DEPRESSED.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно должно измениться? Вы задали градиент, если я вас правильно понял, но ни где его более не меняете.

Answer (score 1):

transition-duration: 3s; добавляется к .maindiv:hover .pclass2

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maindiv {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(53, 13, 80, 0.74), rgba(128, 19, 19, 0.514)), url("https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 37.5rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  position: relative;
}

.maindiv::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.maindiv:hover::before {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}

.pclass {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.pclass2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 120px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  
  width: 400px;
}

.maindiv:hover .pclass2 {
  right: 160px;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="maindiv">
    <p class="pclass">FREE SARAH</p>
    <hr class="line">
    <p class="pclass2">SARAH LIKES TO WATCH CLOUDS. SHE'S QUITE DEPRESSED.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```